# Samsung Windows 10 computer got an update to its sound driver and now I can't play music through bluetooth

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth, samsung-laptop

My computer via Samsung Update told me I had an update for my computer's sound driver. I installed it, thinking it would be fine. Ever since the install, the computer will "connect" to bluetooth speakers but won't play through them. The sound will continue to come through the computer speakers. I've tried restarting my computer multiple times. I've also attempted to use two different bluetooth devices on the computer, but both had the same issue. Neither had this issue before the update, and they both work fine when paired with my android phone. Any idea why the recent driver update caused this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Look for a Samsung audio driver from Samsung support for your computer.

Comment: Check windows sound settings, specifically which device is selected as default